# ¿Cómo agrupar y sumar columnas y conservar registro mas reciente en python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe y el problema es que quiero agrupar los datos y sumar las columnas 'jugado' y 'apuesta_promedio' conservando los datos del cliente de una sola fecha, la mas reciente de la columna 'ultima visita'.

```
Sala   numero cliente           clave ultima_visita jugado apuesta_promedio
Dubai  100    francisco perez   fp100 2018-04-30    500    300 
Dubai  100    francisco         fp100 2018-03-21    1500   350
Dubai  100    francisco         fp100 2018-02-05    400    200
```

esperado:

```
Sala   numero cliente           clave ultima_visita jugado apuesta_promedio
Dubai  100    francisco perez   fp100 2018-04-30    2400   850
```

he utilizado sin éxito lo siguiente:

```
agrupado = df.groupby(['Sala', 'numero', 'cliente', 'clave', 'ultima visita'])['jugado', 'apuesta_promedio'].apply(lambda x : x.astype('float64').sum())
```

esto me sigue trayendo todos los registros.
Existe alguna forma de obtener el resultado que deseo?, he estado pensando en alguna función 'unique', pero igual me enfrento a la eliminación de mis registros que necesitan ser sumados.
Saludos y gracias

Comment: Lo que buscas es considerar a `francisco perez` y a `francisco` como un mismo cliente? La clave o identificador del cliente es la columna `numero`?

Comment: exacto, el identificador es la columna numero, y deseo conervar los datos respecto al numero y ultima fecha de modificacion, en este caso la columna ultima visita

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar generamos un `dataframe`a modo de ejemplo:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""Sala;numero;cliente;clave;ultima_visita;jugado;apuesta_promedio
Dubai;100;francisco perez;fp100;2018-04-30;500;300
Dubai;100;francisco;fp100;2018-03-21;1500;350
Dubai;100;francisco;fp100;2018-02-05;400;200
""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
```

Lo siguiente es generar un nuevo `dataframe` agrupando y sumarizando según lo que has indicado

```
agrupado = df.groupby(['Sala', 'numero']).agg(
                                  {'jugado': 'sum', 
                                   'apuesta_promedio':'sum', 
                                   'ultima_visita':'max'
                                  }).reset_index()
```

Nota que el agrupamiento lo hacemos por `Sala` y `numero`y no incluimos `cliente` (si además corresponde faltaría tal vez agregar `clave`). Las formulas que usamos, son bien claras. Faltaría ahora agregar el nombre del cliente, pero aquel que se corresponda al agrupamiento y coincida `ultima_visita`, para esto usaremos `pd.merge()`:

```
result = pd.merge(df, agrupado, on=['Sala', 'numero', 'ultima_visita'])[['Sala', 'numero', 'cliente', 'clave', 'ultima_visita', 'jugado_y', 'apuesta_promedio_y' ]]
```

Resultado final:

```
    Sala  numero          cliente  clave ultima_visita  jugado_y  apuesta_promedio_y
0  Dubai     100  francisco perez  fp100    2018-04-30      2400                 850
```